# Jsp Servlets Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS). Problem with microsoft code?

Tags: java, servlets, adfs, ws-federation

I have an app that a client requested to connect to an ADFS server. Unfortunately this app is in Servlet technology. JDK 1.8 tomcat 7. According to this [github repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-b2c-java-servlet-webapp-authentication) MS claims that i can achieve this. I cloned this repo and met the prerequisites described (jdk14, maven3, tomcat9). The app works but there is a big problem. Whenever i run this tomcat logs are populated with errors. The worst part is that when i run another app in the same tomcat i see errors coming from this repo-app although i have undeployed it.
This is a sample of the error

```
02-Dec-2020 15:01:09.215 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:337)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
        
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:219)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
```

If anyone has some information about this i would appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: That sample is for Azure AD B2C. Have you converted it to ADFS e.g. created an application group?

Comment: Well this is what i want to achieve through my web app. Single sign on with adfs (token procedure). I do not think this will be more different than the sample. I just need to modify my login procedure. I cannot move forward if i do not fix this error first. Microsoft provides a server for testing with this sample but as i said what it bothers me is the errors.